# File Upload to java server without servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I would like to upload a file (for example an image) to java server using POST request. I do not want to use Servlet or Spring. Is there a way to do this for example using com.sun.net.httpserver?

Comment: What about using [Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652530/how-to-implement-fileupload-in-embedded-jetty)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If not, I would say try that and post the issues here you face any.